# Crear ID´s únicos sin reutilizar los eliminados

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Dispongo del siguiente código de GAS que genera Id´s cuando no existen en la hoja. Por ejemplo, de un array como este `[ [ 1 ], [ 3 ], [ 4 ], [ 5 ] ]`, lee el último número `maxNum`, que en este caso es 5 y mediante `newID` le suma 1 unidad más para que genere el id consecutivo (por lo tanto el 6). Ahora bien, si elimino uno de los id´s existentes (por ejemplo el 5) considera que nunca existió y por lo tanto lo vuelve a crear. ¿Alguna manera para que no repita los id´s que ya hayan sido creados? estos debe ser irrepetibles.

```
function calculoId() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id_Sheet');
const ws = ss.getSheetByName("nameSheet");
const uniqueIDs = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
var maxNum = 0;
 uniqueIDs.forEach(r => {
 maxNum = r[0] > maxNum ? r[0] : maxNum;
  });
var newID = maxNum + 1;
console.log(uniqueIDs);  
console.log(maxNum);
console.log(newID);
return true;
}
```

Comment: podrías guardar en [cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache) o en alguna celda, el último id creado y sumarle 1 cada vez que crees uno nuevo.  Esta forma es considerablemente más rápida que recorrer toda la columna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución más simple es almacenar en alguna celda el último id creado e incrementarlo cada vez que crees uno nuevo. Esta forma es considerablemente más rápida que recorrer toda la columna

```
function calculoId() {
  const cell = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id_Sheet').getRange("nameSheet!Z1")
  const newID = cell.getValue() + 1
  cell.setValue(newID)
  return newID
}
```